# React How to avoid the need for ctrl-click in a multi-select box using?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React and I would like use only click to select/unselect items in multi-select instead "ctrl + click", it's possible in java script and jquery as the below code

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));
    return false;
});
```

**is there are a way to be implemented with React ?**

My Code Like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Col, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [field, setField] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="my_multiselect_field">
      <Form.Label>My multiselect</Form.Label>
      <Form.Select multiple aria-label="Default select example" multiple value={field} onChange={e => setField([].slice.call(e.target.selectedOptions).map(item => item.value))}>
        <option value="field1">Field 1</option>
        <option value="field2">Field 2</option>
        <option value="field3">Field 3</option>
      </Form.Select>
    </Form.Group>
  );
}
```

Comment: What does your React code look like?

Comment: @DBS question details updated